# Firebase Flutter Authentication login environment

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, jwt, google-signin

I am building a Flutter app with Firebase Authentication. I am trying to find a way to ensure that the communication going to my backend is actually from the app I wrote and uploaded to the stores. I thought that I could be using the JWT provided as a result of the firebase login for this task to ensure that the logins can be made only from within my app.

I figured out that certain signs in email and password methods can be logged in from outside the app it was intended for. However, since google and phone sign-in require an SHA-1 key to be [registered to the firebase project](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth), I wondered if I could ensure that by restricting logins to these methods, only the trusted app can generate valid JWT and communicate with my backend.

I do not know much about security, so I would really appreciate any tips.

Comment: There is already a lot of info on this subject, I'd recommend reading up on [CSRF mitigation strategies](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) and implementing what you learn there.  Luckily there are already mature modules out there in every language that you can just pop into your project without needing to understand how all the plumbing works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Brian. I am not sure if there is a misunderstanding. I was not asking ways to prevent requests being forged on behalf of my users. I am instead trying to find a way to prevent a legit user with valid credentials to interact with my backend through other means than my application. Do you think this still applies? I am having a hard time making the connection.

Comment: Yes, each request to your backend must contain your JWT token and a unique CSRF token that's generated on each request.  Any request to your backend, legit or not, that doesn't contain the unique CSRF token would be rejected.  It prevents forging attacks in addition to what you're asking.

Comment: These CSRF tokens are generated by the server, and passed to the client to be included in the reply, right? How does this stop this kind of attack if the connection was started from outside the app in the first place? If you mean that I should generate this in the client side, couldn’t the algorithm to generate this token just be decompiled and used outside the app?